# How to change the nodeid in freeopcua for python?

Tags: python, opc-ua, node-opcua

I've searched for hours how to change the nodeid of my objects/variables in [freeopcua](http://freeopcua.github.io/), but unfortunately can't figure it out.

Can someone with more experience help me out here please?

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow this question, but it covers exactly what I was looking for. Based on the examples of the library you only get numeric node IDs and I wanted to have a string identifier instead, which basically is the actual question, here.

Answer (score 2):

Should someone face the same problem - the answer is:
While you creating a variable inside a object you can change a nodeid as follows:

```
myvar = myobj.add_variable("ns=22; s=whatYouWantToCallYourID", "NameOfYourVariable", 0)
```

Where ns=22 is a namespace of 22 (just for example) and s=whatYouWantToCallYourID the string name of the NodeID. 0 is the initial value of your variable that is beeing created with the above code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. This worked for me as well and I haven't found this hint anywhere else in the docs or whatnot.